# Return number of days in a given month of a given year

Tags: c++, for-loop, switch-statement

I wrote a program that, given the month number and the year, returns the number of days in that month:

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <conio.h>
void main() {
  clrscr();
  int month, year, i;
  cout << "give the year \n";
  cin >> year;
  cout << "give the month\n";
  cin >> month;
  for (i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
    i = month;
    switch (month) {
      case 1:
        cout << "number of day in month is 31\n";
        break;
      case 2:
        if (year % 4 == 0) {
          cout << "the number of days is 29 \n";
        } else {
          cout << "the number of days is 28 \n";
        }
        break;
      case 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12:
        cout << "the number of days is 31 \n";
        break;
      default:
        cout << "the number of days is 30 \n";
        return;
    }
  }
  return;
}
```

When I give the month number `3`, it returns `the number of days is 31`, so it works fine. But when I give `1` or `2`, the output is

```
number of day in month is 31
number of day in month is 31
number of day in month is 31
.
.
.
.
```

How can I make it return only `number of day in month is 31` or `number of day in month is 28` if the case is `2`?

Comment: `if (year%4==0) {cout <<"the number of days is 29 \n";}`.  Not if `(year%100)==0`, unless `(year%400)==0` is also true.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year:  *Every year that is exactly divisible by four is a leap year, except for years that are exactly divisible by 100, but these centurial years are leap years if they are exactly divisible by 400. For example, the years 1700, 1800, and 1900 are not leap years, but the year 2000 is.*

Comment: but it is (year%4==0) in the script not %100

Comment: @AndrewHenle how to fix the repeating in case 1 and 2

Comment: @AymenDerradji: And that will be wrong in 2100, which is not a leap year.

Comment: @gnasher729 so %400==0 is the best way ???

Comment: @AymenDerradji: There is no "best". There is right and there is wrong. Years divisible by 4 are leap years. Exceptions: 1900, 2100, 2200, 2300, 2500 but not 2000 and 2400. "Right" checks exactly three conditions. Follow what Andrew wrote, and write a unit test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't repeat the calculation/ don't use the loop. Use the switch case syntax properly.

And your leap year calculation is wrong. It should be like this:

```
if ((year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || (year % 400 == 0)){
    cout << "the number of days is 29 \n";
}
else {
    cout << "the number of days is 28 \n";
}
```

A year is leap year if **it is divisible by 4 but not divisible by 100** or **it is divisible by 400**

Answer (score 2):

You have a loop where `i` runs from 1 to 12.

Inside that loop you do

```
switch (month)
```

But you probably mean

```
switch (i)
```

Otherwise you're just repeating the same calculation 12 times.

Comment: so i will only do it with switch without for

Answer (score 0):

lazy way:

```
#include <ctime>
static int GetDaysInMonthOfTheDate(std::tm curDate)
{
    std::tm date = curDate;
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 29; i <= 31; i++)
    {
        date.tm_mday = i;
        mktime(&date);

        if (date1->tm_mon != curDate.tm_mon)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return i - 1;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution as C++ Class:

```
struct CwCalendar
{
    static bool leapYear(uint year)
    {
        return (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || (year % 400 == 0);
    }
    static uint daysInMonth(uchar month, uint year)
    {
        switch (month) {
        case 2:
        {
            if (leapYear(year)) return 29;
            return 28;
        }
        case 1: case 3: case 5: case 7: case 8: case 10: case 12:
        {
            return 31;
        }
        default:
            return 30;
        }
    }
};
```

Build on @Md. Monirul Islam answere which explains leap year calculation.

Unit test against Qt QDate class from year 1 to 3001:

```
void unittest_CwCalendar()
{
    for (int year = 1; year <= 3001; ++year) {
        for (int month = 1; month <= 12; ++month) {
            int day = CwCalendar::daysInMonth(month, year);
            if (0) day--; // insert error, set day before last day
            if (0) day++; // insert error, set not existing day in month

            QDate d(year,month, day);
            if (!d.isValid() || d.addDays(1).month() == d.month() )
            {
                std::cerr << "Error :: "
                          << "year: " << year
                          << " month: " << month
                          << " day: " << day << '\n';
                std::cerr << std::flush;
                exit(-1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```